# implement a checksum validation in my string, digit or token

Tags: c#

For this example, I'm using LINQPad and I choose a simple example. For real I'm implementing the solution on a web API.

Let's say I have a user and a role. For some reason, I would like to check nobody manipulated the user and role at some point of my code.

Alice is a basic user so:

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("alice:basicuser");
string token= Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
string revert = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(foo));
Console.WriteLine($"{token} --> {revert}");
// YWxpY2U6YmFzaWN1c2Vy --> alice:basicuser
```

In my system, I give a token to Alice. Alice doesn't know how I encode or convert or generate this token but she can guess. And if she guess she can easily send me false token like

```
string decode = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("YWxpY2U6YWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcg=="));
Console.WriteLine($"{decode}");
// alice:administrator
```

So I would like to add to this validation element that is the result of an operation between my user and role that my user cannot guess.

For example but too obvious and risky: I take first and last letter of my user and my role to create the token:

```
// alice:administrator:aear
```

What C# method/function should I use?

Comment: Don't encode / decode, hash (with salt) instead. use a server side long, hard to guess secret string in addition to the salt. done properly, it's very hard to hack. Even better, don't use this information to define roles. Instead, use it to identify that it's really alice. Keep the role information safely in your database, never send it to the client side.

Comment: I will hash (with salt) too but this is not about my question here. Let's say I have 2 token with 2 purpose. I must be able to decode this token. For some very good reason I won't explain here (too long) I cannot check the role in my database. they must be sent with the token.

Comment: "So I would like to add to this token a third element that is the result of an operation between my user and role that my user cannot guess." hence hashing instead of decoding. again, with proper salting it's very hard to hack. btw, I've edited my first comment. You should also read the part I've edded.

Comment: Another option would be to add check chars to your token. These can be adaptation of the luhn10 algorithm or a checksum or whatever. This way, if a user fakes a token they must match also the check chars. (at least 2 different algorithms)

Comment: Yes a chescksum... that the word. I edited the title and some information on my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a strong limitation on the size of your token, the most secure way to ensure it has not been modified is to append a [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). In short, a HMAC is a hash protected by a secret key. If you don't know this key, it's impossible to forge it.

In your case, you would need to generate a random secret key that you would keep on the server. Then, you would generate your token the way you already do, generate the corresponding HMAC using this secret key and then send the token + HMAC to the user.

When the user send you his token, first thing you will do is check if the HMAC is correct. If not, then you reject the token.

The .Net framework has everything needed to generate and verify HMACs, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are going the wrong way. Client should never tell server what user and role he should get. Instead, a client should authenticate in your application and get priviligies. Only server decides who are you and what can you do.

I see two valid approaches here.

You can use **database** with token column (in fact, just a password).
You can generate them or make users generate them, you can even use random values:

```
|   Token (passwd)    |   User   |   Role    |
----------------------------------------------
| a7KxmjakQkoOpqJ41Jd |  alice   | basicuser |
```

Now, you give this "a7KxmjakQkoOpqJ41Jd" to alice and she can use it to authenticate in your applications. She can't modify her roles or substitute her login. The only vulnerability is that she can guess other users' tokens if they are too weak (weak or predictable random generator in case of tokens, or weak password policy in case of passwords).

Another way is to use **encryption** (something like bearer authentication does work). Take all the public and insensitive data about user and encrypt it with your private key. Then give it to alice. She (anybody) can decrypt data with your public key and read it, but nobody can modify it. You can use the same public key to ensure that this token was issued by you.

As I understand from your question, you want to give alice her login, role and some hash of these two values, but you provide too much information. If someone collects this data, he can detect your hashing algorithm, it is just insecure. Also, changing the role of alice would lead to token refreshment.